# Destroy a mock in Python after the test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

Let's say I have a couple of tests like these:

```
class TestMyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def SetUpClass(cls):
        cls.my_lib = MyLib()

    def my_first_test(self):
        self.my_lib.my_function = Mock(return_value=True)
        self.assertTrue(self.my_lib.run_my_function(), 'my function failed')

    def my_second_test(self):
        # Some other test that calls self.my_lib.my_function...
```

And let's say I have something like this in MyLib:

```
class MyLib(Object):

    def my_function(self):
        # This function does a whole bunch of stuff using an external API
        # ...

    def run_my_function(self):
        result = self.my_function()
        # Does some more stuff
        # ...
```

In my_first_test I am mocking my_lib.my_function and returning a True when the function is executed. In this example, my assertion is calling run_my_function(), which is another function from the same library that among other things, it calls my_lib.my_function. But when my_second_test is executed I don't want the mocked function to be called but the real one. So I guess I would need to destroy the mock somehow after running my_first_test, maybe during tearDown(). How do I destroy that mock?

I edited my original question to add more details since looks like it was not that clear, sorry about that.

Comment: Is your object running tests on itself and mocking out its own implementations? That's asking for trouble. Normally you have a test class (using the built in `unittest`) that's distinct from the class being tested. EDIT - And that will create a new object instance for each test, so no need to reset the state.

Comment: I took his use of `self.assertTrue` to indicate that this was all inside of `unittest.TestCase` but that it was just omitted for simplicity. If that's not the case, something is very wrong.

Comment: @PatrickCollins But what about `self.my_lib.my_function`? That looks like either the implementation of the test object or he's keeping an object around in the set-up. Perhaps you're right and it's the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class TestYourLib(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_lib = MyLib()

    def test_my_first_test(self):
        self.my_lib.my_function = Mock(return_value=True)
        self.assertTrue(self.run_my_function(), 'my function failed')

    def test_my_second_test(self):
        # Some other test that calls self.my_lib.my_function...
```

Then the `Mock` is "destroyed" by passing out of scope when `setUp` is called for the next test case.

Comment: You got something seriously confused. `run_my_function` isn't being mocked, it's the method under test. Mocking what's being tested makes 0.00 percent sense. It's `my_lib...` that being mocked, because `run_my_function` is using it and we don't want to test `mylib` too. That is a completely standard use case and the only way to not mess with `my_lib` would be to dependency inject *everything* which is frowned upon and not really practical.

Comment: @delnan It seems wrong to me that you'd need to change some property of `my_lib` to get `run_my_function` the way you want -- that looks to me like dependency injection after its been instantiated. I would expect to see something like `MyLib(the_object=Mock(...))` or `self.my_lib.run_my_function(the_object=Mock(...))` as reasonable, loosely-coupled implementations. `self.my_lib.my_function = Mock(return_value=True)` suggests clearly that it is something internal to `run_my_function` being mocked, otherwise `my_lib.my_function` and `mylib.run_my_function` have very confusing names.

Comment: I don't think that this test makes very much sense, but it appears to be the one that @Cas is asking for.

Comment: Passing in a Mock as argument is perfect when the thing being mocked has a (non-test-related) reason for being a parameter. But when it's a free function, it's completely pointless to promote it to a parameter. It is useful, for the same reasons that mocking any parameter or object state is useful. And regarding OP's test: It does make a bit of sense (it tests that `run_my_function` correctly forwards the return value). But yeah, it tests implementation details (which is different from *using* implementation knowledge, which can be fine in white box testing).

Comment: Sorry my question was confusing Guys, I appreciate your answers. To clarify what I am trying to do, is to test the functions from my_lib, but some of those methods call some other method from the same library, in my example, run_my_function is a method that make use of my_function to do its job (maybe the names I used for my example were not the best :( ). But when testing one method that has dependency in another, I'd like to mock the method that is not being tested at that moment.

Comment: @PatrickCollins you are right, the second part of your answer is what I needed, instantiating the library in the setUp made the trick. I had instantiated the class in SetUpClass, so the scope was the whole test class so the after setting a mock it was getting set for all the tests.

Comment: @PatrickCollins however the first part of your answer doesn't make much sense to me either, as delnan said, in that case you are mocking the method under test which doesn't make sense since then you wouldn't be testing anything. If you edit that answer I can mark your answer as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: @Cas I edited as you suggested. Let me know if you think it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Destroying the mock won't do it. You'll either have to re-assign `self.my_lib.my_function` or call `Mock(return_value=True)` in a different manner.

The first is what Patrick seems to suggest.